# How to group by with sum and aggregation?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to organise a table with some conditions.
I need to order by `id`, and to add a column that make sum of the same species, with the same `id` (cf.**bold charachter**).

[image]

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: so... have you tried what you wrote in the title? `select id, sum(number) || species group by id, species`

Comment: You would still get multiple rows for different combinations of id and species attribute. It would be clearer as I wrote in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You would not get one row per id but multiple rows for different combinations of id and species attribute.

```
SELECT id, species, SUM(number) FROM species_table GROUP BY id, species
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a first step but it doesn't concatenate to get all the species column in a single one group by id ? I think it's something with the concat_ws function but doesn't know how.

Comment: You can check this link about aggregating multiple rows into one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943433/postgresql-concat-ws-like-function. Also, here is the link where it is explained how to use nested aggregated functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107666/nested-aggregate-functions-with-grouping-in-postgresql